# estimate uncertainty of experimental data

Tags: regression, poisson-distribution, measurement-error, uncertainty

I evaporate atoms in a vacuum chamber and use a quartz crystal microbalance to measure the deposition rate. Specifically, I measure the resonance frequency of the quartz crystal and use that to calculate the total mass that has been deposited on its surface. I am interested in relatively low rates, so I measure the frequency over a long period of time (on the order of minutes). I'm looking for the best way to estimate the rate, including uncertainty.

For example, I can fit a straight line to the accumulated mass vs. time and estimate the rate from the slope, but the corresponding uncertainty is usually very small, several orders of magnitude lower than what I would expect.

I think the best way would be to repeat the measurement many times (I've done this - this is the reason why I think the uncertainty estimate from the slope is too low), but this isn't always possible. I am considering treating this as a counting experiment and letting the error be the square root of the mean number of atoms that condense on crystal during experiment duration (i.e. Poisson distributed). I'm not sure what the best way is to estimate the uncertainty - any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why does small uncertainty mean that you need to do something else?

Comment: @MichaelChernick, OP indicates that the experimental assessment of uncertainty is higher than the theoretical based on some kind of regression.

Comment: Unless the number of atoms is very low, and I mean like a few hundreds, Poisson wouldn't make a lot sense, in my opinion. It'll look like Gaussian

Comment: @MichaelChernick You're right, the uncertainty of the actual measurement is small, and that's OK. It's repeatability that's the issue. If I run the experiment again I get values that are far outside the estimated uncertainty.

Comment: Is this for a space Mission? Note that there is a big difference between the uncertainty *in the sedimentation rate* (the slope of the regression line) and the uncertainty *in the sedimentation times*. Repeat the experiment as many times as it's reasonably affordable, refit a regression line for each experiment and look at the confidence intervals for the slope: do they overlap most of times? If not, then I can see the following explanations: 1) very few atoms deposit for each experiment (@Aksakal comment); 2) the systematic variation between experiments is much larger than the [ctd]

Comment: [ctd] sampling variation in each experiment, because of variation of experimental conditions (drift in the microbalance? Residual pressure in the vacuum chamber? Temperature? Number of atoms? The acceleration of gravity shouldn't change :)); 3) the linear model is inappropriate, i.e., deposited mass is not a linear function of time. What do you expect from physics? Should it be linear or, e.g., exponential?; 4) errors aren't normally distributed. Please add the usual diagnostic plots for linear regression to your question, so that we can understand if this could be the case.

Comment: Uncertainty of measurement is a big topic; this is an authoritative document http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/guides/gum.html. I agree with @DeltaIV that between-experiment uncertainty may be substantial.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you estimate the uncertainty based on a single experiment. In this case you're going to miss a lot of sources of errors related to experiment control. You have to estimate the error based on multiple experiments because you already observed higher uncertainty when observing repeated trials. The simplest way is to plug all observations into one equation.

For instance, you have $i=1,\dots,n$ experiments under "the same conditions" (which are clearly not exactly the same in your case), and collect $t=1,\dots,T$ observations for each experiment: $y_{it}$. Now you plug all these $n\times T$ data points into the same regression. This way at least you attempt to take into account the uncertainty of your experiment control. It's not the best way in some cases, but better than running a regression on a single experiment